# Ruby on Rails - Tiny TDS with Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, freetds, tiny-tds

I'm using Tiny TDS in Windows 7 64bits.

Configs:

```
Ruby: 1.9.3
Rails: 4.0.0
Tiny TDS: 0.6.1
```

database.yml

```
development:
adapter: sqlserver
host:     localhost
dataserver: PAVEI-PC\PAVEI
database: TKD_SUBD
username: pavei
password: pavei
```

in rails console

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => 'pavei', :password => 'pavei', :dataserver => 'PAVEI-PC\PAVEI', :database => 'TKD_SUBD')
irb(main):003:0* client.execute("teste")
TinyTds::Error: closed connection
    from (irb):3:in `execute'
    from (irb):3
```

I dont know why connection is closed!

Comment: See the logs. Check firewall.

Comment: windows firewall is off, nothing was printed on logs

Comment: Can you connect to this server with a GUI or other kind of client?

Comment: Yes, see in this image http://oi44.tinypic.com/2qv72p0.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration file is not right. As is mentioned in [TinyTds Readme](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#tinytdsclient-usage), `:host` must be used only if `:dataserver` is blank, and you have both there. But the execution command in the console is correct.

I have same problem, the connection is closed just after client is created, and this happens only when I use `:dataserver` instead `:host`

**Works:**

```
 client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'secret', host: '192.168.0.74', database: 'MyDB'
```

**Doesn't work (connection is closed):**

```
 client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'secret', dataserver: 'MYNTBK\SQLEXPRESS', database: 'MyDB'
```